# Functionality of free()

Tags: c, free

I want to understand how `free()` works. In the example below, how does `free()` know how many bytes are in the block it needs to free?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{     
    char *p= NULL;
    int size = 25;
    p = (char *)malloc(size);

    /* some operation on p */

    free(p);
}
```

Comment: people should not downvote duplicate question. Duplicate question doesnot means that its a low quality question it means that someone other has already asked such question. Asker didnot have searched before posting this question.

Comment: @Mr.32 When you hover over the downvote, it'll show you a context tip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". That sounds fairly accurate, to me. *CLICK*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *implementation specific*, the only thing defined is how it should look like it works to the application, and the implementation is free to use whatever structure it needs to give good performance/low memory use/...

As an example, one way would be to reserve a few bytes before the block returned, and store the size there. For example, if you `malloc()` 25 bytes, it would actually reserve 29 bytes, store the size in the 4 first bytes and return a pointer to the last 25 bytes. `free()` can then take the pointer, subtract 4 and read the size.

Another way would be to store the address/size in a hash table, so that when someone calls `free()`, it can look the size up in the hash table.